# Solution to finding position of 1 in sorted array of 0 and 1

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I got a call from Amazon to attend one of their interview and given a test to write most efficient solution to the below problem.

To find smallest position of 1 in sorted array of 0 and 1. e.g. in array 0000001111 output should be 6.

I tried binary_search on this but that does not utilize property that array has only 0 and 1. Can you give me some better solution.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: Why is the output 1 for `0000001111`? Where's the position 1 in this "array"? Counting from 0 from the left, the smallest position is 6. Where did 1 come from?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `smallest position`? To me it seems that the smallest position is 6

Comment: Refer to [Find first set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set).

Comment: Not sure but think this would be better asked on the Comp Sci  site http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you're counting from the right and it's sorted, the answer will always be either 1 or a not-found error of some sort.

Comment: So how did the interview go? Did you get the job?

Comment: yes :) I Missed the sorted part.

Comment: Apologies for error in question, I corrected it now. I didn't cleared the test as I couldn't come up the efficient solution to detect palindrome singly linked list and binary search tree.

Comment: I am fairly certain that binary search is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the fact that the values are 0 and 1 to write a standard binary search in a more compact way:

```
int firstOne(int[] arr) {
    int[] a = new int[2];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = arr.length;

    while (a[1] - a[0] > 1) {
        int m = (a[1] + a[0]) / 2;
        a[arr[m]] = m;
    }

    return a[1];
}
```

Because of the use of the array `a`, we have the invariant that `arr[a[0]] = 0` and `arr[a[1]] = 1`. If the loop ends, `a[0]` and `a[1]` point to two consecutive array elements, so `a[1]` is the first 1. Note that I ignored special cases (all 0, all 1, or an empty input).

Answer (score 2):

same as binary try this..

```
while
{
   if array[array.length/2] == 1
   {
        if array[array.length/2 - 1 ] == 0
             return
        array = 1st half of array
   }
   else
   {
       if array[array.length/2 + 1 ] == 0
             return
       array = 2nd half of array
   }
}
```

It might be you looking for If there is any idea better than this iam really intrested to learn

Comment: I tried the similar approach but what kept me thinking is that I am not at all using property of array that it is sorted binary array. I think since it is array , so elements will be at consecutive location. So think of it at memory area part of which is completely zero and other half has LSB set to 1. So may be we can use this to come up with efficient solution. memcmp is not that efficient as it is done outside processor cache.

Comment: @NIRAJRATHI I don't think binary can be improved here. The array is of the form AAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBB and you need to find the border between A and B, which can be anywhere in the array. Binary really can't be improved here because there is no extra information to help you find that border in a faster way.

Comment: zero doesn't mean no memory for that... both 1 and 0 takes same size in memory